# Finite group such that $G = H \cup xH$ and $K = \{ y^2 \mid y \in G \}$ with some properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I find this problem on a local contest, but i didn't solved it. Maybe someone can give me some points how to continue?

> We consider $G$ a finite group for such that exists a proper subgroup $H$ and an element $x \in G$ with property $G = H \cup xH$, where $xH = \{ xh \mid h \in H \}$ and subset $K = \{ y^2 \mid y \in G \}$.
>   Show that:
>
> a) $K \subseteq H$
>
> b) If $|G| = 2n$ with $n$ odd, then $K=H$.

What I've got is $H \neq xH$ hence if that was true we get by hypothesis $G = H$ so $H$ is not a trivial group, contradiction.
Is well knowed $|H| = |xH|$ but more I don't know what to do.

$\text{IMPORTANT: I don't want a full solution, just some ideas!}$

Comment: It is $[G:H]=2$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: This for $K=H$ part, right? I suppose $[G:H] = 2$  so H is normal subgroup so it's the smallest so $H \subseteq K$ and by $a)$ we get $H=K$ ?

Comment: For a) note that, if $f$ denotes group's operation, it is: $f(\complement_GH \times \complement_GH)=\begin{cases}\emptyset&\text{if }H=G\\H&\text{if }[G:H]=2\\G&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: so think of the two cases  $g \in H$ and $g \in \complement_GH=xH$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be an assumption that $H$ is a *proper* subgroup of $G$. Otherwise $H=G$ would qualify, and (b) would not hold.

Hint for (a): $y\in G$ is either of the form $h\in H$ or $xh\in xH$. So look at each of these squared.

Hint for (b): Note $|H|=n$ is odd. Show that $h\mapsto h^2$ is injective (use that $h^{n+1} = h$). Conclude that every $h\in H$ is a square.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103977/discussion-on-answer-by-milten-finite-group-such-that-g-h-cup-xh-and-k).